# Can't correctly import double numbers into C program

Tags: c, file-io, io

I have a txt file formatted this way:

```
MyDepartureTown MyDestinationTown 123.45 Vehicle 12
```

I am trying to import the data into my C program. Here it is the code I am using to acheive just that:

```
void import_city_info(Grafo *G)
{
    char city_dep[20];
    char city_des[20];
    double km;
    char vehicle[12];
    int time;

    FILE *data_file = fopen("data/routes.txt", "r");
    if (data_file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore. Impossibile aprire il file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (5 == fscanf(data_file, "%s %s %f %s %d", &city_dep, &city_des, &km, &vehicle, &time))
    {
        printf("%2.3f\n", km);
        //more code...

    }
}
```

As I try to print out the double numbers, it outputs `0.00`. It's actually importing correctly all the data except the double. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: consider using length with `"%s"` to prevent overflow.  `"%19s %19s %lf %11s %d"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong specifier to read `double`. This will invoke undefined behavior. You need `%lf`.

```
while (5 == fscanf(data_file, "%s %s %lf %s %d", &city_dep, &city_des, &km, &vehicle, &time))
{
```

Comment: Thank you. Was gettin' maaad!